# Append inputs into a form

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to create a simple to do list. one of the things I want to accomplish is to append some inputs into a form after a click using jQuery. 
Unfortunately this is not happening... Who can point me in the right direction and help me append some inputs into the form?

[view in css deck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/am3oqxhb)

the code I'm trying with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var todo_list = $('#todo_list');

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#input').appendTo(todo_list);
});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: Is #input an <input> tag? Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `input` is not an **id** instead it is a **class**. SO it should be called as `.input`

Just change `#input` to `.input`

like this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var todo_list = $('#todo_list');

  $('#add').click(function(){
  $('.input').appendTo(todo_list);
 });
```

Comment: Wow, completely overlooked this one. Awesome, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If #input isn't an existing  tag, it won't work. The appendTo method is used to add some element after another. You are using the ID selector #input, but it doesn't seems be defined. Change your HTML to add, to the <input> the #input ID it will work.

Another way to do this is using something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var todo_list = $('#todo_list');
  var input = $('<input type="text" name="whatever" id="whatever" class="someclass">');

  $('#add').click(function(){
    $(input).appendTo(todo_list);
  });
});
```

Note, this code will only solve the problem of adding a new <input> to the #todo_list, not saving or other stuff besides it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  $('#todo_list').append('<input type="text" />');
});
```

Here follows a [JSFiddle working with the behavior described](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/5WLcN/).